# wpdb->insert: do I need to prepare against SQL injection?

Tags: wpdb

Do I need to use wpdb prepare before wpdb->insert?

If I am inserting values into a wordpress table using wpdb->insert, do I need to "clean" my data before inserting it or does this method (wpdb->insert) do that for me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you shouldn't prepare or escape the data, this is done for you by the `wpdb` class.

From the [wpdb class reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#insert-row):

> **data**:
>
> (array) Data to insert (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped).

If, however, you were writing your own SQL rather than using the `insert` method, then yes, you should escape using `prepare`.

Comment: To add a note: Both `insert` & `update` don't need that. But it should be used with `query`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a warning for the wpdb class.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

> A Warning
>
> Some of the functions in this class take an SQL statement as input.
>   You must SQL escape all untrusted values you incorporate into the SQL
>   query to prevent SQL injection attacks. Check the documentation to see
>   if the function you plan to use escapes SQL for you or expects it to
>   be pre-escaped.

**So I read this as - the wpdb class does not automatically prepare or escape the data for you.**

I am pretty sure that if you cannot trust 100% the data source in your code, then I suggest using the prepare class(?).

Do not think that using the prepare class will fix it without using the prepare class properly. I am fairly new to this so please post any corrections as a reply if I am not right.

$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = %d AND name = %s", $id, $name );

In the above statement, there are 2 extra attributes. One for the ID and one for the name. As far as I read it, each corresponds in order to the number of items in your query. Also %s = string, %d = integer and %f = float.

Also, from my reading, if you don't put the extra attributes in, then prepare will actually do nothing. There will be a warning, but if you switch that off, perhaps you won't know.

Here is an example from the class reference itself where they add a prepare class into an INSERT below.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

> $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(     "       INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta         (
>   post_id, meta_key, meta_value )       VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )   ", 
>           array(        10,         $metakey,       $metavalue  )  ) );

My concern is that the upvoted answer is incorrect according to the same page that 'nobody' references. I am assuming that you use prepare() but not other standard php methods of escape because I took this answer as correct as well... until I dug deeper.

Anyway... perhaps things have changed since the original answer.

Comment: hmmm, this sounds more like a question than an answer

Comment: Accepted answer is correct. When you use functions like `$wpdb->insert()`, $wpdb->update()` or `$wpdb->delete()` data should be RAW. In a situation where you use e.g. `$wpdb->query()` and pass SQL statement as input, you should escape untrusted data.

Comment: nmr, I think I understand now. So to clarify... for my sanity... what you used as an example is 'the insert method and 'the delete method' as opposed to the examples that I used of using 'the query method' ... (%wpdb->query). Do I delete my answer? Or leave it?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to prevent against SQL injections when you use - wpdb insert or wpdb delete.[image]

See the following links:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks